# Improper use of "Whenever"

Tags: grammaticality, conjunctions

I increasingly encounter people who misuse "whenever" when they really mean "when":

> Whenever I first came to St. Louis, I lived with my Aunt Judy...

Bugs me to death. Obviously they are talking about a one-time event, not "every time I visited St. Louis", which would be a valid use of "whenever".

Is this a common misuse? Is this a regional thing (St. Louis, MO, USA)? This isn't a valid alternate use, is it?

Comment: Yuck!  This is my number one english language pet peeve!

Comment: I don't think this is regional and it is quite common. My opinion is also that it is still quite wrong.

Answer (score 5):

I keep hearing a couple of people from Kentucky and Oklahoma say things like, "Whenever I was ten years old". Like they were ten years old more than once. Or, "Whenever I was in High School". This just seems like the word should be "When" in these circumstances. It drives me crazy when I hear this.

Comment: Yes, this is the usage that bugs me when I hear it.

Answer (score 4):

This usage, where it means "at an unspecified/uncertain time" is fairly common.  I usually hear it (and say it) in a construction more like, "Whenever it was that I first came to...".  I don't know if you would also object to this structure.

In terms of being "valid", the dictionary lists:

> adv.
>
> 1. At whatever time.
> 2. When. See Usage Note at whatever.
>
> conj.
>
> 1. At whatever time that: We can leave whenever you're ready.
> 2. Every time that: The child smiles whenever the puppy appears.

Surely you say things like "whenever you want" -- this is the same "whenever".

Comment: These are certainly ok in most dialects, but I think the OP was asking about cases where a speaker clearly does _not_ mean an unspecified time.

Comment: I meant unspecified in the sense of "It happened at a specific time, but I don't know/recall/care what that time was."  That is what the sentence means, right?

Comment: Those two conj. uses are the ones that "feel right" to me. Your "Whenever it was..." example seems to make sense, but I hear people use it all the time even when (whenever??) they are talking about a specific defined time, not just an uncertain time.

Comment: Are you saying you are hearing it used interchangeably in place of "when"?  Can you give me an example, maybe framing the sentence in the context where it is weird/wrong?

Comment: @Kosmonaut: See the other answers. "Whenever I was ten years old" is a pretty typical (mis)use of the kind I am describing. To me, it clearly should be "When I was ten years old". In my experience, they don't mean "Whatever year it was that I turned  ten years old", which is the case you are describing ("whenever it was that...")

Answer (score 3):

This is a known dialect feature of the American South (but I can't find a reference right now). I don't know that it has a different meaning from "when" in your dialect.

Comment: I have also heard it from a Northern Irelander. It is clearly a part of some people's dialect, so it is offensive to call it a "misuse", though I too found it strange when I first heard it.

Comment: I live in Georgia and can't ever remember ever having heard *whenever* misused in this way.

Answer (score 3):

I have noticed this as well among youth in Northwest Arkansas. I first started noticing it about 6 months ago. My wife has started misusing "whenever" as well. It should only be used to refer to indefinite or unknown times, not a single, specific time. Correct use: "Whenever I am in St. Louis, I visit Busch Gardens." Incorrect use: "Whenever I was 5 years old, I went to Busch Gardens."

Comment: "Every single time out of the one time I was five..."

Comment: This is exactly the misuse I was talking about. Still drives me nuts...

Comment: What about the example in the question?

Answer (score 1):

The first time I heard it used incorrectly was on MTV by a young man from TN.  Since then I have noticed news reporters on HLN and CNN use it as well.  My first thought was that it was about "location" but I am now inclined to believe that it is either about education or people hearing it and thinking that they, themselves  have been wrong all their lives. "Whenever I was at the fire...." I too cringe when it is improperly used.

Comment: This seems more like a comment than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is standard usage in Northern Ireland. I've never heard it anywhere else (I live in the Republic, and I've never heard it here or from my English relatives).